# SQL: Delete old messages except the last X messages for each user

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm building an activity stream, so old messages fall off the end and will never get seen again. So, I'd like to regularly delete old messages. However, I don't want it to look like a user has no activity, so I want to leave a minimum of X posts in each stream.

Simplified, my "messages" table has a "mid" (message ID, primary key), a "uid" (user ID), a "created" date (UNIX timestamp), and a "message." So what I want is to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM messages
WHERE created < ? AND mid NOT IN (
    SELECT mid FROM messages m GROUP BY uid HAVING mid > (
        SELECT mid FROM messages WHERE uid = m.uid ORDER BY mid LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?
    )
)
```

However, when I try the query inside `NOT IN()` by itself, it returns no results. Additionally, I don't think it works to `SELECT` from the same table you're deleting from.

I'm okay with 2 queries if necessary, but I hope it isn't necessary.

I tried searching around and there are a bunch of results on how to delete all but the last record, but I didn't find anything about deleting all but the last N records.

Comment: Is your order determined by the message id, or solely by the timestamp?

Comment: Solely by the timestamp.

Comment: Why have you tagged this with mysql AND postgresql?  Which are you using?

Comment: It's cross-platform -- it has to work on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this question for a [mysql] solution to the "top n per group" problem:

[How to SELECT the newest four items per category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867)

Once you have the set consisting of all rows in the "top n per group" (that's what you want to keep). You just have to delete those rows not in that set:

```
delete x
where x.mid not in ( select mid
                     -- where top n per group criteria
                   )
```

Here's another link that looks at the same problem:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Comment: Choosing this as the solution for giving me a better way to frame my question.

Answer (score 1):

This simulates sql servers windowed function row number it numbers each message by date.  Then only deletes messages with a number greater than 10.  You might need to flip the equality between  l.created >= r.created.

```
delete from messages
where mid in 
    (select  l.mid from (  
    select l.mid,l.created, count(*) as num
    from messages as l
    left outer join messages as r
        on l.mid = r.mid
        and l.created >= r.created 
    group by l.mid, l.created) a 
    where a.num > 10    
   and l.created < ?);
```