# Is it possible to apply limit on group size?

Tags: mysql, limit, greatest-n-per-group

```
select * from tabName limit 25
```

by above query I get 25 rows and I want to add a limit in this result for 5 record per group.

Is it is possible?

Comment: Downvoter, please throw the OP a bone and let him know why. :)

Comment: This is the infamous (poorly handled in MySQL) n-per-group which is similar to greatest-n-per-group. I have added the greatest-n-per-group tag because those approaches can be used as it is just a refinement of n-per-group. I hope the (newly) associated answers will be of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer to [How to SELECT the newest four items per category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867) for the standard solution.  This question comes up regularly on StackOverflow, and we try to tag it `greatest-n-per-group`.  But in most cases, people are asking about the greatest *1* per group, for which different solutions are used.

Note that most of the solutions for greatest-n-per-group require you to have some idea of the *order* of rows in each group, so your query can decide which ones belong in your result set and which ones are the "extras" that should be excluded.

For a solution that doesn't care about the order, MySQL doesn't have ANSI SQL:2003 windowing functions, so solving this problem is a little awkward.  But you can do it with some user-variable tricks:

```
SET @g := NULL;
SET @n := 0;

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT IF(groupCol = @g, @n:=@n+1, @n:=1) AS n, @g:=groupCol AS groupCol, *
  FROM tabName
  -- put ORDER BY here if applicable
) AS t
WHERE n <= 5;
```

Replace `5` with any other limit you want to put on the rows per group.