# Store the whole query result in variable using postgresql Stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, procedure

I'm trying to get the whole result of a query into a variable, so I can loop through it and make inserts.

I don't know if it's possible.

I'm new to postgre and procedures, any help will be very welcome.

Something like:

```
declare result (I don't know what kind of data type I should use to get a query);
select into result label, number, desc from data
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question body does not reflect any research effort from your side. Anyway, you may take a look on [this other SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296034/stored-function-with-temporary-table-in-postgresql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to read PostgreSQL documentation about [cursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html).

But if you want just insert data from one table to another, you can do:

```
insert into data2 (label, number, desc)
select label, number, desc
from data
```

if you want to "save" data from query, you also can use temporary table, which you can create by usual `create table` or `create table as`:

```
create temporary table temp_data as
(
    select label, number, desc
    from data 
)
```

see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html)

Comment: Roman, thanks for answering!
I need to query a database and save the result into a variable, and after that manipulate the data. Only after that I want to insert it into another table.
That's why I needed to save the query into a variable.