# MySQL - Join these two queries together with a join or subquery?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

This query returns the data I require given a specific `traceid` value (50 in this example, which is a key that exists in both tables, `tblResults` and `tblTraces`:

```
SELECT count(changed)
FROM (
    SELECT changed
    FROM tblResults
    WHERE traceid = 50
    AND changed = 1
    ORDER BY resultid DESC
    LIMIT 0,20
) as R
```

I want to run this above query against *nearly* every `traceid` (so, selecting 20 rows for each traceid, not just traceid 50, so 3 traceid's would mean 60 rows). This simple select below gets the required `traceid` values:

```
SELECT `traceid` FROM `tblTraces` WHERE `enabled` = 1
```

How can I "glue" the two queries together?

So I imagine a query like the following, except it won't work because the subquery is returning multiple rows (which I want):

```
SELECT count(changed)
FROM (
    SELECT changed
    FROM tblResults
    WHERE traceid = (
                     SELECT `traceid` FROM `tblTraces` WHERE `enabled` = 1
                    )
    AND changed = 1
    ORDER BY resultid DESC
    LIMIT 0,20
) as R
```

Comment: Show us the output of  `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblResults;`

Comment: In table `tblTraces` are distinct `traceid` ?

Comment: Here is an sqlfiddle to show the schema of these two tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c04125/1/0

Comment: Do you really mean both `count(changed)` and `changed = 1` ?  This will return the number of "changed" rows with a maximum of 20.

Comment: Hmm, so there are many rows in `tblResults` with the same `traceid`. I want `count(changed)` of the 20 most recent rows/entries for each `traceid` in `tblResults` (so `ORDER BY resultid DESC LIMIT 0,20`) where `changed = 1`

Comment: The most recent revision of you answer seems to be working, I just need to double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, there is no easy way to do this.  In other databases, you would just use `row_number()`, but it is not available.

Here is one approach, assuming `resultId` is unique on each row:

```
select t.traceId, count(changed)
from (select traceid, ResultId, changed,
             (select count(*) from tblResults r2 where r2.traceId = r.traceId and r2.ResultId >= r.ResultId and r2.changed = 1) as seqnum
      from tblResults r join
           tblTraces t
           on r.TraceId = t.TraceId and t.enabled = 1
      where r.changed = 1
    ) t
where seqnum <= 20
group by traceId
```

If you don't want this by `traceid` and just want the total count, then remove the `group by` and change the `select` to `count(changed)`.

Comment: Phew! That was quite the noodle baker! So, this works perfectly. I just had to remove `and r2.changed = 1`, I have manually checked by  hand the answers it works perfectly. Now I need to make a coffee and spend some time fully understanding this answer, its great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do this. I adapted [Bill Karwin's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1442867/1036439]). See his post for a more thorough explanation.

```
SELECT x.traceId, COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT a.*
    FROM tblResults a
    -- Be sure not to exclude tblResults which are the only record in the trace
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblResults b
      -- We're going to count how many rows came "before" this one
      ON a.changed = b.changed
     AND a.traceId = b.traceId
     AND a.resultId < b.resultId
   WHERE a.changed = 1
     AND a.traceId IN (SELECT traceId FROM tblTraces WHERE enabled = 1)
   GROUP BY a.resultId
  HAVING COUNT(*) < 20      -- Eliminate rows ranked higher than 20
   ORDER BY b.resultId DESC -- when we rank them by resultid
) x GROUP BY x.traceId
```

The outer query is only for verification that each traceid contains no more than 20 selected records, and the inner query is the result set you're actually interested in.

Comment: You need `LEAST()`, not `MIN()` there. But I had the same thought.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not satisfied with this answer, it's probably the easiest for smaller tables:

```
SELECT tblTraces.traceid, LEAST(20, SUM(tblResults.changed))
FROM tblTraces
    LEFT JOIN tblResults
    ON tblTraces.traceid = tblResults.traceid
WHERE tblTraces.enabled = 1
AND tblResults.traceid.changed = 1
GROUP BY tblTraces.traceid
```

The limit on column really complicates the joining.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear if you need a count of these (limited to 20 per trace) results or the actual results. For the count only, there is a simple way:

```
  SELECT t.traceid,
         LEAST(COUNT(*),20) AS cnt
  FROM tblTraces AS t
    JOIN tblResults AS r
      ON r.traceid = t.traceid
  WHERE t.enabled = 1
    AND r.changed = 1
  GROUP BY t.traceid ;
```

test in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a04f/9)**

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do an inner join like so

```
select count(traceid)
  from tblResults a inner join tblTraces b on a.traceid = b.traceid
   and b.enabled = 1
   and a.changed = 1
```

Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: The `LIMIT 20` per trace complicates things.