# Select 3 of each unique ID from SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a SQL question. I am not very strong with using SQL and thought that someone here could give me a hand. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have a SQL table that consists of the following:

```
id INT,
lat VARCHAR(255),
lon VARCHAR(255),
timestamp TIMESTAMP
```

This table consists of several gps locations from multiple different ID's. The Primary key is the ID and timestamp.

What I need to do is to select the latest 3 sets of coordinates from each unique id. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to SELECT the newest four items per category?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category)

Comment: I wish the duplicate thingy was a bit smarter

Comment: @BillKarwin I am trying to run through the answers from the other post. The problem I am having is A)Like I mentioned, I am not very well-versed in SQL, and B)I am trying to do this for one table. So, I don't really need the joins. That does appear to be close to what I am trying to do however. I am just trying to figure it out at the moment.

Comment: @jwebster, follow the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. There are many answers to that general type of problem. Granted, 9 out of 10 are solving the greatest *1* per group, which is solved differently. But some of the solutions are for your case, greatest N per group.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after quite a few edits, the below should definitely work. I tested it and it was clean.

```
SELECT t.id, t.lat, t.lon, t.timestamp
FROM table t
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2
  ON (t.id = t2.id AND t.timestamp < t2.timestamp)
GROUP BY t.id, t.lat, t.lon, t.timestamp
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
ORDER BY t.id, t.timestamp desc;
```

Note, I find it super frustrating that both Oracle and MySQL still don't support an order by/limits in subqueries! Would have made this much simpler the first time around...

Comment: Any results on trying to run this?

Comment: I have tried to run that just now, but I will apparently have to change the version of MySQL that I am currently using in order to use it. I am getting the following error: Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

I truly do appreciate the help and the attempt at it. This one is proving to be a bit trickier of a problem than I expected it to be.

Comment: which version are you using? it looks like 5+ supports it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Comment: I believe it should definitely work with the answer above, so long as the MySQL version supports the use of any, all, etc. for subqueries.

Comment: Running the SELECT @@Version returns that I am running '5.5.34-cll-lve'

Comment: And running that from within MySQL Workbench and/or PHPMyAdmin both returns the same error of this version not supporting it. So I will just have to either find another way, or change versions of SQL.

Comment: I made a slight change that does not require 'any'. Let me know if this new query works.

Comment: Any update on this? I am very interested to see if this works actually, since it would be the skeleton of a good generic query.