# SELECT 3 comments for each post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, limit

I have a table `comments`

```
id | comment | post_id |
1     Hey       1
2     Hey       2
3     Hey       2
4     Hey       3
5     Hey       1
```

I want to get 3 comments for each posts.

I did something like this below.

`"select * from comments WHERE post_id IN(1,2,3) LIMIT 3"`

But this yields me only  `3 rows`.

But i want max `3 rows` for each `post_id` not total `3 rows`.

Any help where i am going wrong ?

Comment: can u explain a bit @violator667

Comment: This is called "greatest N per group". It is frequently asked and not particularly straightforward, and I'm searching for a good existing answer to point you toward...

Comment: Ah, [here it is-- an excellent answer by Bill Karwin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867)

Comment: can u show @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: @RockFellerDumbstep radar's answer below should be exactly the implementation you need. It expresses the same thing as Bill's linked answer with slightly different syntax.

Comment: RockFellerDumbstep about JOIN @Michaelberkowski latest comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is like doing partition based on post_id and then doing selection of 3 elements in that partition
you can achieve this using mysql variables

```
select id, comment, post_id
from 
(
SELECT id, comment, post_id, @row_number:=CASE WHEN @post_id=post_id THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,
       @post_id:=post_id AS varval
FROM comments
join (select @row_number := 0, @post_id := NULL ) as var
order by post_id, id 
) t
where t.row_number <=3
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: Your table posted at the top has a `comments.id` column. This should be right on track.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7de45/2 It should work as is - I added a couple more example rows to `post_id = 1` to show that those above 3 are eliminated

Comment: opps it was a small mistake got it working! dont mind but can u explain whats happended here homie ? @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: What do you mean by "whats happened here"? Do you want to know how this works?  It assigns a variable to each grouped `post_id` and increments it for every row. The `join` initializes the variables to 0. In the end, the outer query limits to only rows where the variable row numner was `<= 3` to provide your limit per group.

Comment: Where will the `where` clause go @MichaelBerkowski `post_id IN(1,2,3)`?

Comment: @RockFellerDumbstep, you can have in the inner query before the order by. check here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e04817/3