# Finding Most Frequent Values in a Table Associated with a Parent Id Column in Another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables being joined.  They have a one-to-many relationship.  I would like to make a query that pulls the most frequent of the "many" table *for each of the parent id's.*

I have a query like this that is in the beginning phases of what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT  p.profile, up.value, COUNT(*) AS theCount FROM `profiles` AS p
JOIN user_profile AS up ON p.id = up.profile_id
GROUP BY `profile`, `value`
ORDER BY p.profile ASC, theCount DESC;
```

Now the problem with this query is that it will show all values from the many table, and just group them with most to least.  For example:

If table `profile` has values of `val 1`,`val 2` and table `user_profiles` has values of `Apple`, `Apple`, `Orange` with a parent_id of `val 1`, and `Pear` for `val 2` in the first table, the query above will group them like this:

`val 1`, `Apple`, `2`

`val 1`, `Orange`, `1`

`val 2`, `Pear`, `1`

Now what I WANT is this:

`val 1`, `Apple`, `2`

`val 2`, `Pear`, `1`

I only want to show the highest value for the parent.  Or if the case there is only one value (e.g. val 2) then show that.

*Now, I can easily do this in a subquery* (Do a Limit 1 for each parent value; order by `theCount` DESC).  **However**, is there (1) a way to do this **without a subquery**? or (2) a MySQL function or some other way to do this?  I am trying hard to keep these queries very quick and high performance.

If you can show me that a subquery will not hinder performance here, I will select that as an answer as well.

Comment: Using the ["greatest N per group" pattern here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category) and joining against a subquery that produces the counts, this should be achievable and performant. A joined subquery will not suffer the same severe performance problems a subselect would.

Comment: If you could setup this sample set over at http://sqlfiddle.com with your two tables, that would help.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I believe you have the exact idea with what I need based on the link you provided.  If you think a subquery would be ok, Then I should try that and compare time on the queries.

Comment: Although it is a little bit conceptually hacky, Gordon's method using group_concat() and string manips is probably faster and is certainly easier to implement than the user variables method. Try it out.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  I tried it, it is very fast actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this type of problem, I think the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick is the easiest method in MySQL:

```
SELECT profile, substring_index(group_concat(up.value order by theCount desc), ',', 1) as MostCommonValue,
       theCount
FROM (SELECT  p.profile, up.value, COUNT(*) AS theCount
      FROM `profiles` p JOIN
            user_profile up 
            ON p.id = up.profile_id
      GROUP BY `profile`, `value`
     ) pv
GROUP BY profile
ORDER BY p.profile ASC, theCount DESC;
```

This method has short-comings.  For instance, if `value` can contain a comma, you need a different separator.  More importantly, there is a maximum length to the `group_concat()` intermediate value (but you set the parameter to have a larger value).  But, it works quite well in many cases.

Comment: Well, this certainly works fast.  And you did it without a subquery... so I think this is the answer.