# MYSQL: Limiting rows per whereIn()

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, where-in, right-join, sql-limit

users Table

**id**

---

user_comments Table

**id | user_id | content | created_at**

---

I have a list of user IDs, and I want to grab the latest 3 comments for each user id.

```
SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

This will grab the last 3 comments from *all* matching IDs, I want the last 3 comments for *each* ID. 1 query without unions preferred.

I have tried right joining the table on itself but I cant seem to get it right.

** **Edit: I cannot rely on the id column for ordering, it must use the date column.**

Thanks.

---

** **My Final Solution**

```
SELECT user_comments.* FROM user_comments
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_comments user_comments_2
ON user_comments.post_id = user_comments_2.post_id 
    AND user_comments.id < user_comments_2.id    
where user_comments.post_id in (x,x,x) 
GROUP BY user_comments.id 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3 
ORDER BY user_id, created_at
```

The answer proposed by @PaulSpiegel did work for me (with caveat), however I ended up going with the above join solution that I made using info from this thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867)

mentioned by Bill Karwin.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: SELECT * FROM user_comments WHERE user_id=1 OR user_id=2 OR user_id=3 OR user_id=4 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 3;

Comment: Do you have an AUTO_INCREMENT column?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - Yes, the id columns are auto_inc.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón - I have hundreds of user ids in some cases, ideally I wouldn't have to dynamically generate the query like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867

Comment: @BillKarwin - I was able to get it working with proper date ordering using that thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `id` instead of `created_at`, you can compare the `id` with the 3rd highest `id` per user. Which you can find in a subquery with `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2`. For the case that a user has less than 3 comments use COALESCE (or IFNULL) to select all comments with `id >= 0`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_comments c
WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  AND id >= COALESCE((
    SELECT id
    FROM user_comments c1
    WHERE c1.user_id = c.user_id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 2
), 0)
ORDER BY user_id, id DESC
```

If you can not use `id` for ordering..

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_comments c
WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  AND created_at >= COALESCE((
    SELECT created_at
    FROM user_comments c1
    WHERE c1.user_id = c.user_id
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
    OFFSET 2
), '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
ORDER BY user_id, created_at DESC
```

Note that you then might (though unlikely) get more than 3 comments, if the 3rd and the 4th comment have the same timestamp.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot rely on the id column for ordering the comments since in my application they can be saved as a draft, and published at a later date.

Comment: @magnito That also works using a timestamp - but read the note. I've also added the missing ORDER BY clause in the subquery.

Comment: I was able to get this mostly working, however I ended up going with the join solution proposed in the thread that BillKarwin mentioned. It doesnt have the same issue with duplicate dates and is faster (in my situation).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select * 
from (
    select *, 
        @currentRank := if(@prevId = user_id, @currentRank, 0) + 1 as rank, 
        @prevId := user_id
    from user_comments
    order by user_id, created_at desc) as user_comments 
where rank <= 3
```

Inner query uses **SQL @ variables** that change the value from row to row. Comments of a particular user will be grouped together because of `order by user_id`. `@currentRank` variable will be storing row rank in a particular group. `@currentRank` will be zeroed out when new group starts.

The result is quit optimal as it needs RDMS to iterate over each record of `user_comments` table only once. However the outer `where` clause will be executed afterwards.