# PHP/SQL retrieve BOTH categories and latest topic

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently "practicing" making a forum. I've never done anything this big before and it's been going on for a while. Pretty much everything works, but I can't get it to select the proper latest topic from the categories on the index page.

Here is the SQL:

```
    $sql = '
    SELECT topic_id, topic_subject, topic_by FROM topics WHERE topic_cat IN (1,2,3) ORDER BY topic_cat DESC LIMIT 3
    UNION
    SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories WHERE cat_id IN (1,2,3)
    ';
```

I will also supply some pictures of the two tables from the database.
Here is the categories table.
[image: CATEGORIES]

This is the topics table.

[image: TOPICS]

The basic idea here, as you may tell from the SQL, is that it selects the three first categories and then selects the latest topic from those three categories.

The code for placing the information retrieved by sql into a table containing everything.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not display categories. Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
    } else {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            echo 'No categories found in the database.';
        } else {
            echo '
                <table>
                <h3>Top 3 Categories</h3>
                <tr>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Latest Topic</th>
                </tr>
            ';

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr>
                    <td class="leftpart">
                        <h3><a href="category.php?id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</a></h3>' . $row['cat_description'] . '
                    </td>
                    <td class="rightpart">
                        <a href="topic.php?id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }

            echo '</table>';
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what else to add to this, so if there are any questions, please comment it and I can either answer it there or add additional information to the main post!

Comment: Maybe this question helps You: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category

Comment: what you mean by latest topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are actually looking for is [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) which basically used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them.

Here are the different types of the JOINs in SQL:

- (INNER) JOIN: Returns records that have matching values in both
  tables
- LEFT (OUTER) JOIN: Return all records from the left table, and the
  matched records from the right table
- RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN: Return all records from the right table, and the
  matched records from the left table
- FULL (OUTER) JOIN: Return all records when there is a match in either
  left or right table

this what you want :

```
SELECT
    topics.topic_id,
    topics.topic_subject,
    categories.cat_id,
    categories.cat_name,
    categories.cat_description 
FROM
    topics 
    JOIN
        categories 
        ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id 
ORDER BY
    topics.topic_date DESC LIMIT 3;
```

The reason you are not getting proper results with union have a look here :

The UNION operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements.

- Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of
  columns
- The columns must also have similar data types
- The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

Your tables does not meet the above creatiria

Comment: will it give three categories or three topics or total three rows ?

Comment: total of three rows remeber we have joined the tables into one now @AhmedGinani

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, this works, but if someone posts 2 topics in the same category it shows 2 of the same category, is there any way to get rid of this? If what's happening is unclear I can send a screenshot

Comment: after SELECT add DISTINCT so that is becames `SELECT DISTINCT...` @Chaost

Comment: Did not work, the whole syntax is now `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM topics JOIN categories ON topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id ORDER BY topics.topic_date DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: what does it show? you might need to also add another order by which will be the cat ID desc or topic id desc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from topics inner join categories 
 on topics.topic_cat = categories.cat_id
order by topics.topic_date desc limit 3
```

Basically, a inner join will do this.You can select particular field instead of * if you want.

Comment: Okay, should I keep the "Union select" below this?

Comment: No.  Just this query.

Comment: May I know Why Negative?

Comment: Okay, so I tried this and it somewhat works. First of all it displays every category, although I only want the first 3 as this is the "home" page(I can probably fix this myself). It also just makes more of the ones that have several topics in it. So basically it displays for honor twice with each topic in it

Comment: @Chaost you need to add LIMIT 3

Comment: @BikashPaul not my downvote but I believe u got the downvote because of `select *`

Comment: Yes. I know it may be the reason. I had left it to the questioner. and pointed out that also.

Comment: Had some trouble with the server right after i uploaded the new file with the new code. It resolved itself quickly to my surprise :p It definitely worked! Thank you so much :)