# Optimize sql query to use indexes or rewrite sql

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, innodb

I have sql query

```
SELECT 
  bd2.*, 
  bdmax.last_video, 
  bdmax.number_videos 
FROM 
  video bd2 
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT 
      bd.video_cat_id, 
      MAX(bd.last_poster_time) AS last_video, 
      COUNT(bd.video_id) as number_videos 
    FROM 
      video bd 
    GROUP BY 
      bd.video_cat_id 
    ) AS bdmax 
    ON bd2.video_cat_id = bdmax.video_cat_id 
      AND bd2.last_poster_time = bdmax.last_video;
```

[image]

Table keys are

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`),
  KEY `video_cat_id` (`video_cat_id`),
  KEY `video_user_id` (`video_user_id`),
  KEY `video_time` (`video_time`),
  KEY `video_urn` (`video_urn`),
  KEY `last_poster_time` (`last_poster_time`),
  KEY `video_username` (`video_username`),
  KEY `video_approval` (`video_approval`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=45619 ;
```

How can optimize this query to use indexes?

Comment: It already is using your indexes? You query the whole table so a scan isn't unperformant.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Can You rewrite this sql query?

Comment: It's fine like it is. Because you are querying the whole table, the whole table has to be read. The query planner is giving you a good plan

Comment: May be need  create new index?

Comment: **Why** do you think your query needs to change? I don't see any problem with it

Comment: Slow query log shows that this query don't use undexes.

Comment: Yes it does. It does an index lookup and an index scan. You may find that a *different* result will be faster, but the `bdmax.number_videos` implies that you need to *count all the rows*

Comment: Thanks for explains. So, no need doing anything to optimize? This is very huge query for mysql.

Comment: I don't know how you are using the result. can you omit the rowcount in some circumstances?

Comment: I need only cat ids, cat names, last 3 videos with post times in each cat id

Comment: So measure the performance of a query that selects those

Comment: Have another code for this   $categoryId = (int) $categoryId;

  $sql = '
   SELECT v.*
   FROM video v
   WHERE video_cat_id = ' . $categoryId . '
    AND video_approval = 1
   ORDER BY video_time DESC
   LIMIT 0, 3';
  $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

Comment: May be make this query without join? Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867

Answer (score 0):

Don't clutter things by putting the table name at the beginning of column names.  Then this 'composite' index

```
INDEX(cat_id, last_poster_time, id)
```

will help the subquery (by being "covering") and the `JOIN`.

Part of this query is "groupwise max".  But the `COUNT` means that optimizations for the max are not useful.

Comment: Thank You for answer! Now table have keys  
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`),
  KEY `video_cat_id` (`video_cat_id`),
  KEY `video_user_id` (`video_user_id`),
  KEY `video_time` (`video_time`),
  KEY `video_urn` (`video_urn`),
  KEY `last_poster_time` (`last_poster_time`),
  KEY `video_username` (`video_username`),
  KEY `video_approval` (`video_approval`),
  KEY `video_cat_id_2` (`video_cat_id`,`last_poster_time`,`video_id`) 
It's ok? https://image.ibb.co/fDo4Aw/query.jpg

Comment: Good.  But now you can get rid of `KEY video_cat_id (video_cat_id)` as being redundant (same as the left most column(s) of the new index).  Does it run faster?  That is the real deciding point.

Comment: I can delete that index, and create only that You adwise, do it?

Comment: Looks like you have already added the  better index.  This would remove the unnecessary one:  `ALTER TABLE video DROP INDEX video_cat_id;`

Comment: Now table have keys  
  
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`),
  KEY `video_user_id` (`video_user_id`),
  KEY `video_time` (`video_time`),
  KEY `video_urn` (`video_urn`),
  KEY `last_poster_time` (`last_poster_time`),
  KEY `video_username` (`video_username`),
  KEY `video_approval` (`video_approval`),
  KEY `video_cat_id` (`video_cat_id`,`last_poster_time`,`video_id`)

https://image.ibb.co/coRHfw/query.jpg  

Many thanks for all!!!!