# Laravel get n results per group

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables : tbl_properties and tbl_property_images. I need to select latest 3 images of each property along with `property_id`.
I tried with sub query with limit

```
DB::table('properties as p')
->leftjoin(DB::raw("(select property_id, property_image_id, image
                     from tbl_property_image 
                     where property_image_status = 1 
                     group by  property_id 
                     having count(*) = 3)  as tbl_imgtemp") , 'imgtemp.property_id', '=', 'p.property_id')
->where('property_status',1)
->get();
```

This returns total  3 records. please help me how can i do that.
How can I select 3 images per property?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results

Comment: This may be a very non trivial problem in Laravel.

Comment: is it fine if you get images in comma seperated string just like image1,image2,image3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SELECT the newest four items per category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category)

Comment: @Prateik Darji yes. thats fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use following query to get 3 images per property, I have used id column of images table to pick latest images assuming id column is set as auto increment

```
SELECT p.*,i.*
FROM properties  p
JOIN(SELECT i1.property_id,i1.property_image_status,i1.image
    FROM tbl_property_image i1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_property_image i2
      ON (i1.property_id = i2.property_id AND i1.property_image_id < i2.property_image_id)
      WHERE i1.property_image_status = 1
    GROUP BY i1.property_id,i1.property_image_status,i1.image
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
) i
ON p.property_id = i.property_id
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/KRF41401)

Another approach using [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) if you need only a single column from images table

```
SELECT p.property_id , p.title,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(i.image ORDER BY i.property_image_id DESC),',',3) images
FROM properties  p
JOIN tbl_property_image i ON p.property_id = i.property_id
WHERE i.property_image_status = 1
GROUP BY p.property_id , p.title
```

But this solution has some limitations, As per docs *The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet*

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/ZBBDTW87201)

I have used sample schema and data set for above queries you have to adjust these as per your needs