# How to get only 2 products in loading page for each category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to show two products for each category in loading this page but If I click a category type then it will be showing all of the products.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
   $resultspi= $con->query ("SELECT * FROM products WHERE ORDER BY id ASC"); 
   if ($resultspi->num_rows > 0) {
   while($rowpi = mysqli_fetch_array ($resultspi, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
         $id = $rowpi['id'];
         $types = $rowpi['type'];
         $image = $rowpi['images'];
         $names = $rowpi['name'];
 ?>
      <div class="item <?php echo $types;?>">
           <a href="uploads/products/<?php echo $image;?>" data-rel="gallery[prodcuts]" title="<?php echo $names;?>" class="">
              <img src="uploads/products/<?php echo $image;?>" alt="<?php echo $names;?>" class="thumb mCS_img_loaded" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
              <p class="info"> </p>
           <div class="overlay">
              <span></span>
           </div>
            </a>
       </div>
<?php 
      }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: I used it but I want to get two product for each category in the loading page. But when I click the type it will show all of the product. Please check my live site link.

Comment: you need to check the last code snippet in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867

Comment: That's not my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this query. This code work for me.

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.type,p1.name,p1.images FROM products p1 JOIN products p2 ON p1.type = p2.product_type AND p2.id >= p1.id GROUP BY p1.id, p1.type HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2 ORDER BY type, id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.Name, rs.*
FROM (
    SELECT [CustomerNo], PlanId, Rank()
        OVER (Partition BY PlanId
            ORDER BY [CustomerNo] DESC) AS Rank
    FROM CustomerOfPlan
    ) rs
    INNER JOIN [Plan] P ON P.Id = rs.PlanId
WHERE Rank <= 2
```

> In this sample I have 11 Plans and 16000 CustomerOfPlans but result
>   has 22 records.. why ? I need 2 CustomerOfPlan per Plan.

Comment: when you click on each rs.Id, you can show all of CustomerOfPlans.

Answer (score -1):

Change your query try this instead:
SELECT * FROM products WHERE ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2