# mySQL --> LIMIT selected rows, WHERE column value is same

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

This is my query... `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE content_id in (525, 537) LIMIT 60` This is the SS of result:

[image]

here `content_id` = `537` is selected 5 times. 
(`comment_id` is UNIQUE key )..

My question is: How to limit selected rows by 2, where values of `content_id` is same...
Maximum two duplicate records for each `content_id`... like in this picture:

[image]

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1442867/20860 I previously voted to close your question as a duplicate, but I chose the wrong duplicate. This answer I link to is closer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select comment_id, content_id
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by content_id order by comment_id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 2
```

In earlier versions, one solution is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where (
    select count(*) 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.content_id = t.content_id and t1.comment_id < t.comment_id
) < 2
```